# Angularfire User who can add images (attachments) to their Post

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, firebase, angularfire, image-upload

Not a lot of clear documentation for a person as new to Angular/Angularfire/Firebase as me, at least for what I've been looking for:

Currently, I users can be created and stored in my Firebase backend. Users can create a post. Right now it's based on any of the data the user inputs into the create post form. This works all fine and dandy, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to allow something like image uploading into that post as well.

Basically: I want a user to be able to upload a file like an image with their post, (i.e. a blog article with uploaded images.)

**POST CONTROLLER**
    'use strict';

```
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post) {
if ($location.path() === '/posts') {
    $scope.posts = Post.all;
}

$scope.post = {url: 'http://'};

$scope.submitPost = function () {
    Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref) {
//            $location.path('/posts/' + ref.name()); //
    });
};

$scope.deletePost = function (postId) {
    Post.delete(postId);
};

$scope.upVotePost = function (postId, upVoted) {
    if (upVoted) {
        Post.clearVote(postId, upVoted);
    } else {
        Post.upVote(postId);
    }
};

$scope.downVotePost = function (postId, downVoted) {
    if (downVoted) {
        Post.clearVote(postId, !downVoted);
    } else {
        Post.downVote(postId);
    }
};

$scope.upVoted = function (post) {
    return Post.upVoted(post);
};

$scope.downVoted = function (post) {
    return Post.downVoted(post);
};

});
```

**POST SERVICE**

'use strict';

```
app.factory('Post',
function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');

    var posts = $firebase(ref);

    var Post = {
        all: posts,
        create: function (post) {
            if (User.signedIn()) {
                var user = User.getCurrentUser();

                post.owner = user.username;

                return posts.$add(post).then(function (ref) {
                    var postId = ref.name();

                    user.$child('posts').$child(postId).$set(postId);

                });
            }
        },
        find: function (postId) {
            return posts.$child(postId);
        },
        delete: function (postId) {
            if (User.signedIn()) {
                var post = Post.find(postId);

                post.$on('loaded', function () {
                    var user = User.findByUsername(post.owner);

                    posts.$remove(postId).then(function () {
                        user.$child('posts').$remove(postId);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        addComment: function (postId, comment) {
            if (User.signedIn()) {
                var user = User.getCurrentUser();

                comment.username = user.username;
                comment.postId = postId;

                posts.$child(postId).$child('comments').$add(comment).then(function (ref)   
{
                    user.$child('comments').$child(ref.name()).$set({id: ref.name(), 
postId: postId});
                });
            }
        },
        deleteComment: function (post, comment, commentId) {
            if (User.signedIn()) {
                var user = User.findByUsername(comment.username);

                post.$child('comments').$remove(commentId).then(function () {
                    user.$child('comments').$remove(commentId);
                });
            }
        },
        upVote: function (postId) {
            if (User.signedIn()) {
                var user = User.getCurrentUser();
                var post = posts.$child(postId);


post.$child('upvotes').$child(user.username).$set(user.username).then(function () {
                    user.$child('upvotes').$child(postId).$set(postId);
                    post.$child('downvotes').$remove(user.username);
                    user.$child('downvotes').$remove(postId);

                    post.$child('score').$transaction(function (score) {
                        if (!score) {
                            return 1;
                        }

                        return score + 1;
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        downVote: function (postId) {
            if (User.signedIn()) {
                var user = User.getCurrentUser();
                var post = posts.$child(postId);


post.$child('downvotes').$child(user.username).$set(user.username).then(function () {
                    user.$child('downvotes').$child(postId).$set(postId);
                    post.$child('upvotes').$remove(user.username);
                    user.$child('upvotes').$remove(postId);

                    post.$child('score').$transaction(function (score) {
                        if (score === undefined || score === null) {
                            return -1;
                        }

                        return score - 1;
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        clearVote: function (postId, upVoted) {
            if (User.signedIn()) {
                var user = User.getCurrentUser();
                var username = user.username;
                var post = posts.$child(postId);

                post.$child('upvotes').$remove(username);
                post.$child('downvotes').$remove(username);
                user.$child('upvotes').$remove(postId);
                user.$child('downvotes').$remove(postId);
                post.$child('score').$transaction(function (score) {
                    if (upVoted) {
                        return score - 1;
                    } else {
                        return score + 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        upVoted: function (post) {
            if (User.signedIn() && post.upvotes) {
                return post.upvotes.hasOwnProperty(User.getCurrentUser().username);
            }
        },
        downVoted: function (post) {
            if (User.signedIn() && post.downvotes) {
                return post.downvotes.hasOwnProperty(User.getCurrentUser().username);
            }
        }
    };

    return Post;
});
```

**CREATE POST FORM**

```
        <form class="" role="search" ng-submit="submitPost()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Word" ng-model="post.category">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="post.title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="post.url">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="post-content" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Content" ng-model="post.content"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default is-form-toggle">Submit</button>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default is-form-toggle is-close-button" />
        </form>
```

***Anything else needed from me? As you can see, the form doesn't have a file input yet because I'm just not sure what to use at this point. Hopefully someone can at the least steer me in the right direction! Thanks a lot.***

Comment: Unclear what the question is here. There is a lot of code in your example like upvote and downvote that seems superfluous. Additionally, the code seems to do what you've asked--submitting form post to Firebase. Is there an error or issue with it? Can you simplify this to a digestible question?

Comment: @Kato Are you a firebase employee?  I've come to expect you on all firebase questions.