# JS vote system {{bindings}} gives null on click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The error does not show up in the developer tool so I guess its probably got to do with the data itself and how its read. Both {{upVote}} and {{downVote}} starts with no value and show null on click. Somehow the buttons are all linked? I was setting up each vote to each item.

**Background**
Voting system, with separate up and down scores (not netted as a single vote score).
Would like for the scores to persist in the database.

I have not thought about limiting votes per user but if you have thoughts there, feel free to include in your reply. Thanks!

**The JS files**

```
  $scope.upVote = function () {
    if ($scope.voteType == "down") {
        $scope.upVote++;
    }
    $scope.upVote++;
    $scope.voteType = "up";
  };

  $scope.downVote = function () {
    if ($scope.voteType == "up") {
        $scope.downVote++;
    }
    $scope.downVote++;
    $scope.voteType = "down";
  };
```

**Post is saved in the $scope.post as:**

```
  $scope.post = {               
    title:      '',
    upVote: 0,
    downVote: 0
  };
```

**The button is in the html as such:**

```
  <i ng-click="downVote()" 
    class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x"  
    ng-class="{true:'downVote', false:''}[vote=='downVote']"></i>
```

Comment: Are you setting `$scope.vote` in your controller?

Comment: The voting codes are under MainCtrl, which in turn is attached to the main state in app.js file. Or do you mean dependencies?

Comment: throw it in a jsfiddle or plunkr?  Then we can see what you mean and tinker with it for a minute.

Comment: @thataustin sure, gimme some time, ill set it up and replicate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope` is the same controller-wide. It doesn't change within `upVote`.

```
angular.module('starter').controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, Post) {
  $scope.posts = Post.all;
  $scope.upVote = function () {
    $scope.upVote++; // NOT the upVote property of the clicked post
    ...
  };
});
```

You'll want to grab the post from `$scope.posts` like this:

```
angular.module('starter').controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, Post) {
  $scope.posts = Post.all;
  $scope.upVote = function (post) {
    post.upVote++;
    ...
  };
});
```

Pass `post` in your ng-repeat:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(postId, post) in posts">
  <i ng-click="upVote(post)" ...></i>
  ...
</div>
```

This way, you'll reference the clicked post, instead of the properties of `$scope` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I reference posts as postId here. So i should add an additional line in the js as '$scope.postId.voteType = "up or down"'? And would downvote($index) be able to reference properly because of existing postId structure? Sorry about the hassle, still not too familiar with this.

Comment: Yep. You could pass `downVote(postId)`, then your handler would accept the `postId` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, a big hug from me!! Im still trying to figure out. I chanced upon this and slightly understand your `postId` suggestion but understanding still pheripheral. And I think some work needed to refactor the factory to store votes. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942861/angularfire-user-who-can-add-images-attachments-to-their-post`
Btw, does `var post = $scope.posts[id]` overwrite the previous $scope.post = {}?

Comment: It IS confusing. I can probably word my answer better.. I just need to think on it a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66008/discussion-between-thinkerer-and-scott-mcdermid).

Comment: no need for all that postId stuff, can pass the post item itself as argument

Comment: @charlietfl would you mind explaining why that still works? Besides the main post page (with list of posts), im also trying to fit it in the post/postId page but its not working if html is upVote(postId) but it works if its upVote(post), however the scores on the 2 pages dont sync until another vote is cast.